# how to translate windows folder path to linux folder path

Tags: linux

I have an application running on linux which reads image file path from db and show it... similarly there is another windows based application which reads the same db for image file path and shows it. I have configured the SMB service to share the folder with windows...

The problem is that when the linux app stores the image path it uses the path as /data/images/file.tip and windows app cannot read this file because the path is not absolute... same is the case if windows app modifies the db it uses \server\images etc.,

how do i translate windows path to linux and vice versa...

Comment: Do you have the source code of applications?

Answer (score 0):

In your application, can you not specify an OS Flag/Variable, and only store the image file name.

Then based on OS, look in XXX folder for that file.

So store "Image.jpg" in DB, and on the Windows App open "C:\Image.jpg" and on Linux open "/home/user/Image.jpg"

Comment: thanks for the answer... these are not hardcoded paths... user can specify any folder... usually on linux they share folder through samba and use that path for linux as well as for windows. If the windows app stores the image then how do i convert it to local linux path and similarly if linux stores it, how do i convert it to windows path. The path and share name is user defined and they can have multiple shares.

Comment: @Kashif There is no general mapping... Samba can share any path as any share name, so you might have to start reading the smb configuration to try and work out any mapping.

Comment: Hmmm, Interesting... If you share something, does it then get saved in a certain location on the other person's computer? If so, could you do something like this -- Save the folder path of each shared file, replace "\" or "/" with dashes, and save that edited folder-path as a folder in the other users computer. Then put the files in those folders respectively. (If that made sense to you)

Comment: @Idiot211 thanks for your response (also thanks everybody) and sorry for my late reply. Here is what I proposed so let me know if you think this is the correct apporach.

Comment: @Idiot211 Basically, the current system was not designed to share rasters between linux and windows apps but it was general thinking that it should work. Here is what I proposed. It is obvious that Windows cannot share Linux paths directly because Windows uses UNC path (as “\\server\share\filepath”) to identify files/folders whereas Linux does not follow the same UNC syntax.

The only solution is that both apps should support UNC standard. So, the app should translate the native path to UNC before storing it in db and do the vice versa when reading it back from db.

Comment: i meant to say we couldn't find any solution out of the box... so i proposed that we must have to make code changes...

Answer (score 0):

The `/` and `\` are OS specific, so when you retrieve a data from database, try first to replace `/` with `\` if you are in windows, or `\` with `/` if you are on windows.